# How to play audio that listed and execute listview.OnItemClickListener?

Tags: android

Please help me with this one I am struggling to play an audio file from my list of audio file that is displayed in listView.

```java
public void dostuff(){
       listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
       arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
       getMusic();
       arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arrayList);
       listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               //I want to play it here whenever the user clicks the list.
           }
       });

    }
```

and here is where I fetch my songs in the form of external content.

```java
public void getMusic(){
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor songCursor = contentResolver.query(songUri, null,null,null,null);

    if(songCursor != null && songCursor.moveToFirst()){
        int songTitle = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int songArtist = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int songLocation = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

        do{
            String currentTitle = songCursor.getString(songTitle);
            String currentArtist = songCursor.getString(songArtist);
            String currentLocation = songCursor.getString(songLocation);

            arrayList.add(currentTitle + "\n" + currentArtist + "\n" + currentLocation);

        }while (songCursor.moveToNext());


    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: first you need to notify your adapter after adding data in your list

Comment: how can i notify my adapter ? please give me some example?

Comment: simple add this after adding data in your list **`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`** outside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simply you can use MediaPlayer and play the audio file on listView item click like as**

```
public void audioPlayer(String path, String fileName){
//set up MediaPlayer    
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
try {
    mp.setDataSource(path + File.separator + fileName);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```